# I wrote a JavaScript to move a cat on canvas: "ฅ(*ΦωΦ*) ฅ" But the cat jumps weirdly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I created a script that uses HTML input buttons to move a cat on canvas. Each click moves the cat by 10 pixels in the direction that is clicked (moveUp(); moveDown();moveLeft(); moveRight();). This script works fine for the first 10-20 clicks, but then the cat eventually jumps around or is stuck in one spot.

I have no idea why it behaves in this way. can anyone help?

The program is on jsfiddle, you can test it out

https://jsfiddle.net/rockmanxdi/h2sk2sjz/2/

JavaScript code is hereunder:

```
let surface=document.getElementById("drawingArea");
let ctx=surface.getContext("2d");
let cor_x;
let cor_y;

/** draw a cat 
    *   input the coordinates x and y for the center of the cat
    *   does not return, output the drawing only.
    */
let drawCat = function (x, y) {

        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(x, y);
        ctx.fillText("ฅ(*ΦωΦ*) ฅ", -20,-5);
        ctx.restore();

        };

let updateCoordinate = function(x_increment,y_increment){
        console.log("before:" + cor_x + "/" + cor_y);
        cor_x += 10 * x_increment;
        cor_y += 10 * y_increment;
        console.log("updated:" + cor_x + "/" + cor_y);
};

let moveUp = function (){
    updateCoordinate(0,-1);
    console.log(cor_x + "/" + cor_y );
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,surface.width,surface.height);
    drawCat(cor_x,cor_y);
};


let moveLeft = function (){
    updateCoordinate(-1,0);
    console.log( cor_x + "/" + cor_y );
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,surface.width,surface.height);
    drawCat(cor_x,cor_y);  
};

let moveRight = function (){
    updateCoordinate(1,0);
    console.log( cor_x + "/" + cor_y );
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,surface.width,surface.height);
    drawCat(cor_x,cor_y);   
};

let moveDown = function (){
    updateCoordinate(0,1);
    console.log(cor_x + "/" + cor_y );
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,surface.width,surface.height);
    drawCat(cor_x,cor_y);  
};

let reset =  function(){
    cor_x=surface.width/2.0;
    cor_y=surface.height/2.0;
    console.log(cor_x + "/" + cor_y );
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,surface.width,surface.height);
    drawCat(cor_x,cor_y); 
}

drawCat(200,200);
```

html body:

```
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="drawingArea" style="border:solid">cat image</canvas>
<p>
    <input type="button" id="resetBtn" value="reset" onclick="reset();" />    
</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="upBtn" value="Up" onclick="moveUp();"/>    
</p>
<p>
    <input type="button" id="leftBtn" value="Left" onclick="moveLeft();"/> 
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="rightBtn" value="Right" onclick="moveRight();"/>    
</p>
    <p>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="downBtn" value="Down" onclick="moveDown();"/>    
</p>
```

By the way, I put console.log() inside updateCoordinate(); and move UP/Down/Right/Left(); functions to track the value of the x and y coordinates of the cat. Press F12 to track the value.

Comment: I like the problem statement

Comment: She doesn't move but she jumps ?

Comment: This is running fine in Firefox, I clicked around about 100 times. What browser are you using?

Comment: idk what youre talking about the jsfiddle works perfectly in ff

Comment: When does she jumps? When you click on some of the below buttons?
For me it works fine in Chrome

Comment: Please provide exact click steps to reproduce.  P.S. That looks nothing like a cat.

Comment: I used chrome. I clicked the up/down/left/right randomly, about 30 times, it is stuck or then suddenly jumps to the other spot. I tested it on school's computer and my pc, the bug exits.

Comment: @DiWang doesn't seem to happen for myself and others.  Is there a chance your drawing is consuming a lot of CPU and taking a long time to catch up from click events?

Comment: @ QZ Support I tested on IE, it works fine. I don't know.......... problem with chrome?

Comment: @DiWang You may consider queuing up the button presses into a stack and then writing a loop to pop them off so that you can do some benchmarking.  If you hit a race condition, you may have simultaneous calls to drawCat.  Most game engines have a timer which process events.  This would also help if/when you add WASD/arrow navigation support.  Another option is to disable all HTML buttons each click until the `drawCat` is completed to avoid click-jacking the CPU (assuming that's what's occurring).

Comment: It does happen for me. I got it to proc by going down and out of border.

Comment: It happened to me when I use chrome and move the cat near the edge of the canvas. I put console.log() to track the x and y coordinates of the cat, the values jump after executing updateCoordinate(); but all values are correct inside the function.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in Chrome, and I can't see anything in code that would lead to what you describe. @QZSupport: There is nothing simultaneous about JavaScript and HTML (except Web Workers, which are not, and cannot be, used here), and so race conditions are not possible.

Comment: @Pamblam try more times, I had the same thoughts as yours.

Comment: I guess this issue is caused by some overflowing stuff, otherwise I can't figure out why the cat would jump to a long distance when I click just one button.

Comment: @Amadan thanks for the clarification in regards to the single-thread nature of JavaScript and [Web Workers](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html).

Answer (score 2):

1) I replaced only all let to var (everything is working good):

```js
var surface=document.getElementById("drawingArea");
var ctx=surface.getContext("2d");
var cor_x;
var cor_y;



/** draw a cat 
 * input the coordinates x and y for the center of the cat
 * does not return, output the drawing only.
 */
var drawCat = function (x, y) {

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.fillText("ฅ(*ΦωΦ*) ฅ", -20,-5);
  ctx.restore();

  };

var updateCoordinate = function(x_increment,y_increment){
        console.log("before:" + cor_x + "/" + cor_y);
        cor_x += 10 * x_increment;
        cor_y += 10 * y_increment;
        console.log("updated:" + cor_x + "/" + cor_y);
};

var moveUp = function (){
    updateCoordinate(0,-1);
    console.log(cor_x + "/" + cor_y );
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,surface.width,surface.height);
    drawCat(cor_x,cor_y);
};


var moveLeft = function (){
    updateCoordinate(-1,0);
    console.log( cor_x + "/" + cor_y );
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,surface.width,surface.height);
    drawCat(cor_x,cor_y);  
};

var moveRight = function (){
    updateCoordinate(1,0);
    console.log( cor_x + "/" + cor_y );
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,surface.width,surface.height);
    drawCat(cor_x,cor_y);   
};

var moveDown = function (){
    updateCoordinate(0,1);
    console.log(cor_x + "/" + cor_y );
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,surface.width,surface.height);
    drawCat(cor_x,cor_y);  
};

var reset =  function(){
  cor_x=surface.width/2.0;
  cor_y=surface.height/2.0;
    console.log(cor_x + "/" + cor_y );
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,surface.width,surface.height);
    drawCat(cor_x,cor_y); 
}

drawCat(200,200);
```

```html
<body onload="reset();">
<main>

<!-- place your HTML code within the main -->
    
    <canvas width="400" height="400" id="drawingArea" style="border:solid">cat image</canvas>
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="resetBtn" value="reset" onclick="reset();" />    
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" id="upBtn" value="Up" onclick="moveUp();"/>    
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="leftBtn" value="Left" onclick="moveLeft();"/> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" id="rightBtn" value="Right" onclick="moveRight();"/>    
    </p>
        <p>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" id="downBtn" value="Down" onclick="moveDown();"/>    
    </p>
</main>

</body>
```

It is bug with let variable:

From console log:

> (index):96 before:160/390
>
> (index):99 updated:160/400
>
> (index):126 160/280

Within updateCoordinate: cor_x = 160; cor_y = 400 BUT within moveRight (or moveLeft, moveUp, moveDown) cor_x = 160; cor_y = 280

Comment: Yes!, that is the problem. Your solutions work like a charm!!! why is that Let is causing the problem? I thought let is a better version of var.

Comment: @DiWang, I sent the information about this bug to the google chrome support

Comment: @DiWang, there https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659915